# C fgets skips user input, even when flushing buffer

Tags: c, string, input, buffer, fgets

I am trying to get input from the user and fgets is skipping over the very first input. I know the reason is fgets is reading the '\n' from the previous statement or at least I think that's the reason but I can't seem to fix it

*Note this is part of a larger project*

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define MAX 1000

 int main(void) {

  char  content[MAX];
  char  content2[MAX];
  char  content3[MAX];
  char  content4[MAX];
  char  content5[MAX];
  char  input[4];
  char  input2[4];

  printf("Do you want to continue yes/no?\n");
  fgets(input, 4, stdin);

  if (strncmp (input, "no", 2) == 0) {
     break;
  }
  else if (strncmp (input, "yes", 3) == 0) {
  fflush(stdin);

     printf("Country:\n");
     fgets(content, MAX, stdin);

     printf("Province/state: \n");
     fgets(content2 ,MAX, stdin);

     printf("Postal/zip code:\n");
     fgets(content3 ,MAX, stdin);

     printf("Company:\n");
     fgets(content4 ,MAX, stdin);

     printf("Email:\n");
     fgets(content5 ,MAX, stdin);
  }
```

Comment: That is exactly what's happening. The simplest fix would be to increase the size of `input`. You want *that* call to `fgets` to pick up the newline at the end of yes/no

Answer (score 3):

`"yes"` plus terminating null-character consumes 4 bytes, so `'\n'` remains in the buffer. Allocate more buffer to `input` and pass its new length to `fgets()` in order to read `yes` without leaving newline character in the stream.

Also note that `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly ! As an aside I know it's not related to the question but do you have a personal recommendation on what I should use instead of fflush?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define MAX 1000

 int main(void) {

  char  content[MAX];
  char  content2[MAX];
  char  content3[MAX];
  char  content4[MAX];
  char  content5[MAX];
  char  input[4];
  char  input2[4];

  printf("Do you want to continue yes/no?\n");
  fgets(input, 4, stdin);

  if (strncmp (input, "no", 2) == 0) {
     exit(0);
  }
  else if (strncmp (input, "yes", 3) == 0) {
  fflush(stdin);//this is not portable
  while(getchar()!='\n');//this thing works
     printf("Country:\n");
     fgets(content, MAX, stdin);

     printf("Province/state: \n");
     fgets(content2 ,MAX, stdin);

     printf("Postal/zip code:\n");
     fgets(content3 ,MAX, stdin);

     printf("Company:\n");
     fgets(content4 ,MAX, stdin);

     printf("Email:\n");
     fgets(content5 ,MAX, stdin);
  }
 }
```

fflush() do not work most of the times. use the following code instead

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to add **stdin** in fflush?  You should have something like this:

fflush(stdin);

Comment: No you should not. Calling `fflush` on input streams has undefined behavior. This is terrible advise.